# Cassandra Read time out after mass delete

Tags: cassandra

We create a table “bidresponses”, schema like following.
CREATE TABLE yp_rtb_new.bidresponses (
    time_id bigint,
    campaignid int,
    bidid text,
    adid int,
    adsize text,
    appname text,
…

```
PRIMARY KEY (time_id, campaignid, bidid)
```

)
And set the TTL of this table as 3days. We usually insert 20M records per day. We notice a weird thing. 
In the first 3 days, we could run “select * from bidresponses limit 10”. After the 3rd—mass delete happened because of TTL, when we ran “select * from bidresponses limit 10” , we got time out error; running “select * from bidresponses where time_id=?”,there is no problem. We tried to force compact, it doesn’t help.
After restarting cluster, we could run “select * from bidresposnse limit 10” again. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing Cassandra had to read through a lot of tombstones (data marked for deletion) to find the data. That, and "SELECT * FROM table;" is a full table/multiple partition scan which will cause timeouts, depending on many factors (tombstones, number of nodes, number of partitions etc).

When you specified 'time_id=?', you told Cassandra exactly what partition you wanted which means fewer/no network hops and seeks to find the data.

I found these articles to be particularly helpful and relevant:
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling
https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/10/20/domain-modeling-around-deletes-or-using-cassandra-as-a-queue-even-when-you-know-better/

And now that Cassandra has a date based compaction strategy (date tiered compaction strategy) - you can do some smart modeling around deletes using that as well. 
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/datetieredcompactionstrategy

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But I don't think it is because of tombstones. As I mentioned, I did force compaction. But it does not help. Also when I do "select * from table limit 1", I did not see any thing relevant in log file. And to me restarting will not modify sstable, so my guess is something is wrong in mem, Cassandra must scan keys which were deleted. I wonder if there is a way to clean token ring.

Comment: You are correct - in this case Cassandra will scan the deleted data. That compaction you ran is what turned the TTL'd data into tombstones - it doesn't actually get deleted until GC_GRACE (default 10 days) passes. First instinct is to set GC_GRACE = 0 - but that's also an anti pattern because if your node goes down while deletes are happening, when it comes up, it'll send old data to other nodes causing "zombie" data to appear. Just something to keep in mind. Another trick you can do is turn on CQLSH tracing - this will show you how many tombstones and network hops a query takes (and how long)

Comment: GC_GRACE of my table is 1 hour . As GC_GRACE is less than TTL, My understanding, Cassandra should not add tombstones in sstable. I will turn on tracing to see what happens.

Comment: I turn on the tracing in cqlsh. However, it did not display executions but error message.ReadTimeout: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
Statement trace did not complete within 10 seconds

Comment: You will need to increase the network timeout thresholds http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__PerformanceTuningProps (scroll down a bit) - Or you can try to run the query with partition keys - I'd still expect you to see tombstones. By the way, what does the cluster setup look like? How many nodes? Type of hardware?

Comment: I am running 6 nodes cluster on aws m3.2xlarge, using datastax 's AMI.I already set readrequest and rangerequest as 100s, also set cqlsh client_timeout as disable.Either running select *from table limit 1, or running "select * from table where time_id = expired value", got same time out message.

Answer (score 0):

Force compact will work, previously I had thought nodetool compact will effect on all hosts of cluster.So some hosts were not compacted. After I compacted table on every host. It works.